# Koa pass data from server to client

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, koa

I want to pass through some environment variables from a Koa server to the client. In express I could do something like `res.render('index', { data: 'someData' });`  and then I could access `data`. In Koa I can't see how to do this. It mentions using `context.state` but I can't find any example of how to retrieve this in the client.

Comment: Maybe use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/koa-locals

Answer (score 1):

You can do something similar in Koa, you just need to use the right middleware. Try out [koa-views](https://github.com/queckezz/koa-views) if you're using one of the [supported engines](https://github.com/tj/consolidate.js#supported-template-engines).

Here is a full example (this example assumes you're using Koa v1 and EJS as your templating engine):

**app.js**

```
const Koa = require('koa')
const views = require('koa-views')
const router = require('./routes')

const app = new Koa()

app.use(views(__dirname + '/views', { extension: 'ejs' }))
app.use(router.routes())
app.use(router.allowedMethods())

app.listen(3000)
```

**routes.js**

```
const router = require('koa-router')()

router.get('/', function * () {
  yield this.render('index', { title: 'Home' })
})

router.get('/about', function * () {
  yield this.render('about', { title: 'About' })
})

module.exports = router
```

Just change the `extension` argument you pass to the middleware based on which templating engine you are using.